# CMU Sphinx: how to add keywords in addition to existing vocabulary?

Tags: voice-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4, pocketsphinx

CMU Sphinx comes with a large vocabulary of English words. that is fine however I want to emphasize certain words which I will be using as commands. some of these words are not English words. how can I make sure that Sphinx can understand both my special command keywords and the rest of the English dictionary words?  how can I make sure that my special command keywords take precedence over the rest of the English vocabulary?

Using sphinx, there is a call that I have attempted to use for this purpose:

```
ps_add_word(ps, "OKAY", "OW K EY", 1);
```

However all of the words that I add this way appear to not be recognized any more frequently and any other word.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about programming. If it is, could you edit it to make it more apparent?

Comment: Okay I added the code to make it more clear that this is a programming question

Comment: That looks like a good addition. Not knowing much about sphinx, is that last parameter maybe a weight for the word? As in, making it higher or lower makes the word more or less likely to appear?

Comment: no its a bool telling sphinx to update the dict

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in runtime at the moment. You have to add the word to some grammar/language model. You can find more details about language models in CMUSphinx tutorial:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm

You can also read advanced LM tutorial to understand how to update current language model

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallmadvanced

Comment: okay, So long as I can automate the  LM rebuild process from within my program, that should be  fine.